# Function with set<string> and iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

this is my homework:

Write a function to prints all strings with a length of 3. Your 
solution must use a for loop with iterators.
    void print3(const set & str)

And this is my code:

```
void print3(const set<string>& str){
    string st;
    set<string,less<string>>::iterator iter;

    for(iter=str.begin();iter!=str.end();++iter)
        {st=*iter;
    if(st.length()==3) cout<<st<<' ';
    }
}
```

But I think it's not good. Do someone have a better code? Please, help me to improve it.

-I have another question about iterator

```
 string name[]={"halohg","nui","ght","jiunji"};
        set<string> nameSet(name,name+4);
        set<string>::iterator iter;
iter=name.begin();
```

How can I access name[2]="ght" by using iterator?
I tried  `iter+2` but it has some problems. I think I have to use random access iterator but I don't know how to use it.
Please, help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on improvement:

1. You can get rid of `string st;` and just check `if (iter->length() == 3)`.
2. Another improvement would be to use a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`, since you aren't modifying any of the items.
3. Also, adding `less<string>` as a template parameter is kind of useless, since that's the [default compare functor anyway](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), so it can be removed.
4. And lastly, it's generally a good idea to declare your locals with minimal scope (so they don't pollute other scopes or introduce unexpected hiding issues), so usually you want to declare your `iter` in the `for`.

So it becomes:

```
for (set<string>::const_iterator iter = str.begin(); iter != str.end(); ++iter) {
    if (iter->length() == 3) cout << *iter << ' ';
}
```

That's about as good as you can get, given your requirements.

As for your second question, `set`'s iterator is not a random access iterator. It's a (constant) [Bidirectional Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). You can use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) if you wanted, though, and do:

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator iter;
iter = name.begin();
std::advance(iter, 2);
// iter is now pointing to the second element
```

Just remember that `set` sorts its elements.

Comment: `iter->length() == 3?cout << *iter << ' ':continue;`

Comment: @Vijay: Seriously? You do realize that's not legal, and if it was, it's a bad idea, right?